# Fetching only first row from database

Tags: 8, database

I work with:

```
$mandator = $this->database->select('Mandators', 'm')
     ->fields('m')
     ->condition('idMandators', $mandatorId)
     ->execute()
     ->fetchAll();
```

to retrieve my data from database. The result is an array with 1 array item. How can I retrieve always only 1 object, without the array? Like e.g. `->fetchOne`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
            ->condition('status', 1)
            ->condition('type', 'my_content_type')
            ->condition('field_ref_au', $nid, '=')
            ->range(0,1)
            ->sort('created', 'DESC')
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
$database = \Drupal::database();
$row = $database->query("SELECT column_name FROM {table_name} WHERE column_required = :value", [':value' => $value]);
```

Answer (score -2):

As per my understanding I would say
try to count the number of rows like this:

```
$number_of_rows = db_select('node')->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
```

then iterate to get the first count.

Or:

```
// Get a single record out of the database.
$node = db_query("SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE nid = :nid", array(':nid' => $nid))->fetchObject();
```

Answer (score -4):

You can simply write (example get node) :)

```
$result = db_query('SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.created FROM {node} n)->fetchObject();
```

If you want to get a single value you can use fetchField()

Example (get node title):

```
$node_title = db_query('SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE nid = :nid', 
array(':nid' => $nid))->fetchField();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers. 

db_query() is deprecated/very old. I prefer the database object.

I am wondering, why the query methods are lacking documentation on drupal.org. We should probably add some. Even you could try them or use the evaluate expression function in phpstorm ide. Probably ->fetchField() and fetchObject() can be adapted to the database object.